# Python - ValueError: Cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, valueerror

I'm trying to get the average price of products containing any substrings from a wordlist from a dataframe. I've been able to do so with the following code on multiple spreadsheets -

```
dframe['Product'].fillna('', inplace=True)
dframe['Price'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
total_count = 0
total_price = 0
for word in ransomware_wordlist:
    mask = dframe.Product.str.contains(word, case=False)
    total_count += mask.sum()
    total_price += dframe.loc[mask, 'Price'].sum()
average_price = total_price / total_count
print(average_price)
```

However, one of the spreadsheets throws an error at line -

```
dframe['Product'].fillna('', inplace=True)
```

with

```
ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values
```

I fail to understand why `dframe['Product'].fillna('', inplace=True)` isn't handling this problem.

In desperate need of some help! Thanks!

Comment: If omit it and use `mask = dframe.Product.str.contains(word, case=False, na=False)` it working?

Comment: Are data confidental in problematic file?

Comment: Another idea - `dframe['Product'] = dframe['Product'].fillna('')` should working.

Comment: and yeah, by the way, the data files are confidential as well as too large to skim through.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If first line failed still is possible replace `NaN`s in condition in [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) by parameter `na=False`:

```
mask = dframe.Product.str.contains(word, case=False, na=False)
```

Or try omit `inplace=True` and assign back:

```
dframe['Product'] = dframe['Product'].fillna('')
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve issues with index is to use actually use `index`:

```
# define x
x = "Price"

# make sure to fill Na/NaN values
dframe[x] = dframe[x].fillna('00')

# identify rows that contain a specific value, returns a list of True/False
id_rows = dframe[x].str.contains(r"^ransom")

# save row index for identified rows, basically save all True
row_index = dframe.loc[id_rows].index

# update the chosen variable `x` with new value on identified rows using row index
dframe.loc[row_index, x] = 'cleaned'
```

Does this trick!